# Is there something like user.home to get the \Users\Public directory in java?

Tags: java, windows-7, file-io, filewriter

I would like to use the Users\Public directory to write some files to share between accounts easily, is there a way to get this as a system variable in Java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to find the public directory is

```
System.getenv("PUBLIC");
```

This should get something like `C:\Users\Public`, or if your main drive is `D:`, `D:\Users\Public`.

[This Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Default_Values_on_Microsoft_Windows) is a good reference for Windows environment variables.

Comment: Thanks! The list of string inputs for getenv() that I found was a lot smaller than the wiki article.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a Windows 7 around to check, but if that public directory is stored in an environment variable (e.g. like %APPHOME% or %USERPROFILE%) you can get retrieve its value using `System.getenv()`

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getenv(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use System object

```
System.getProperty("user.home");
```

should get you what you need.

Comment: I think this would return something like `C:\Users\joe` and not `C:\Users\Public`.

Comment: Correct that is what I'm currently using and it gives you the signed in users folder.